# Are there any websites related to publish own's garderns' images/videos?

Tags: container-gardening

I would like to know if there is any web which offers us to upload our gardens' content, and even more, if there are any gardens contest where you could submitt your material via photos or videos and compete!

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a request for a website. Please see https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/634/do-we-really-want-questions-asking-for-off-site-resources for more information.

Comment: I would go to HOUZZ, they have a super forum for you to post pictures of your garden.  They of course make the final decision but if your pictures are good and there is correct information on the plant names and etc. they will love to post your pictures.

Comment: Thank you stormy it ws helpful, clearly helpful because houzz forums look like a place to put your photos and discuss too; thank you.

Comment: @NiallC. I agree. However, pretty soon online contests could replace traditional flower shows or horticultural society gatherings, which would have been a suitable answer had the question not been technology based